# Base causes issue with tuple destructuring

Tags: tuples, ocaml

When `Base` is added to the following code, why does the OCaml compiler expect `h` and `w` to be `int`s? `tup` is supposed to be a tuple - is there a syntactic issue? What is it about Base that causes this error?

```ml
open Base

let () =
  let tup = ("hello", "world") in
  let h, w = tup in
  if h = w then print_endline "equal" else print_endline "not equal"
```

Error:

```
91 |   if h = w then print_endline "equal" else print_endline "not equal"
          ^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Base`, along other Janestreet libraries, discourages polymorphic comparison function and hide `compare`, `(=)` and other operators, with their monomorphic equivalents. More or less arbitrary they chose functions that compare integers (following the SML tradition).

You still can get your polymorphic comparison functions, using

```
open Poly
```

or, locally,

```
let true = Poly.((1,2) = (1,2))
```

Answer (score 3):

The Base library removes polymorphic comparisons. You can use the operators thusly:

```
open Base

let () =
  let tup = ("hello", "world") in
  let h, w = tup in
  if String.(h = w) then print_endline "equal" 
  else print_endline "not equal"
```

Edit: if the explanation didn't make it clear, the Base library is not affecting how OCaml works with tuples.